# XDT Transform of web.config is Append possible

Tags: xml, web-config, xdt-transform, xdt

I'm trying to update an existing appSettings in my web.config. I don't want to replace the entire value, but append my new value to the end. Is this possible?

Current value:

```
<add key="umbracoReservedPaths" value="~/umbraco,~/install/" />
```

Required value:

```
<add key="umbracoReservedPaths" value="~/umbraco,~/install/,~/signalr" />
```

This is what I have currently in my transform file:

```
<add key="umbracoReservedPaths" value=",~/signalr" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes(value)" xdt:Locator="Match(key)"/>
```

Answer (score 6):

You can insert a new element or modify an existing one but XDT transforms do not have the ability to append an attributes value to the original. [MSDN Web.config supported transformations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Insert:

```
<add key="ExampleKey" value="true" 
        xdt:Transform="Insert" />
```

Update value attribute:

```
<add key="ExampleKey" value="true" 
        xdt:Transform="SetAttributes(value)" xdt:Locator="Match(key)"/>
```

Replace element:

```
<add key="ExampleKey" value="true" 
        xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(key)"/>
```